# Send UWP Object from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll, uwp

I have code in C++ that generates a [SpatialCoordinateSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.spatialcoordinatesystem?view=winrt-22000) instance and wish to send this over for my C# code to use. I saw [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-xrdevice-advanced?tabs=mrtk) that a I can simply create such an instance in C# if I have a native pointer to said object, so this was my initial approach. Unfortunately, I am not able to get this to work as I keep encountering access violation errors when trying to pass the pointer from C++ to C#. Any help would be highly appreciated (Note: using the native microsoft function that creates my object in C# is not requires, it was just what made the most sense to me).

C++ (coords is a global variable defined in my header file):

```cpp
void* getCoords() {
    if (coords == nullptr) {
        SpatialLocator loc = SpatialLocator::GetDefault();
        coords = loc.CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation().CoordinateSystem(); 
    }


    return &coords;
}
```

C#:

```cs
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "getCoords"]
public static extern IntPtr getCoords();

public static SpatialCoordinateSystem GetCoordinateSystem()
{
    IntPtr ptr = getCoords();
    return SpatialCoordinateSystem.FromNativePtr(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COM to transfer data from C++ to C#. What you have to do is create similar structure (COORD in your case) in C# code. Then create an interface in C# code and implement one function inside that interface that will accept the argument of type of that structure (COORD). Now, you just have to make a tlb file from the CMD prompt. For making the tlb file, what you have to do is you have to make an empty .bat file (You can name it RegisterTlb.bat) in your working directory (where you have placed your C# code project) and open it with notepad and write following command inside that .bat file:

```
 "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe"  
 "your_C++_exe_name.exe" /tlb your_C#_interface_name.tlb"
```

Here the interface name is that in which you have just implemented you function.
Now just open a command prompt with admin mode and change your directory (with cd command in command prompt) to your c# project directory where your bat file is placed and simply write your bat file name in command prompt (with .bat extension). It will show you the message that type registered successfully. Now you will see that new file with .tlb is been generated automatically in your c# project directory. Copy that .tlb file, paste it in c++ project directory and build the c++ project again. You will see that one smart pointer will be generated in your c++ code the the same name as your interface name (interface that you have created in C# code) but with Ptr suffix like "interface_namePtr". Now you can just call your C# function in C++ as:

```
interface_namePtr->functionName(structureParamenter (COORD) with data)
```

And this will transfer your data automatically.

Do one thing for simplicity (even I got confused here). Make your interface name and your c# project name the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One questions though - When you say I have to “create similar structure inside my C# code” - the data type I’m transferring is a pre-existing type provided by UWP, does this mean I can just skip this initial step and pass the existing type to my new C# interface?

Comment: Additionally, does this work for classes as well or only Structs?

Comment: @ElliotSolskjaer if it's a preexisting type then you have to search online as "what data type in C# is corresponding to UWP in C++". And yes you can pass any type like this whether struct/class/int/long/string. But if it's a user defined type, then u have to create same struct/class in C# also to and pass variable of that type. else you can search corresponding type (as it told earlier) in C# com and pass that type in C# function implementation. example:- to pass string in C# function, compiler will convert String/CString to _bstr_t in C++ code and it will gone as string in C# code.